# Extract text after a string using GREL

Tags: openrefine, grel

I'm trying to add a column based on a column in OpenRefine using GREL.

Here is an example of the original cell data:

`https://www.example.com/notice/search/woa/(type)/SOMEWORD`

I want to extract:

`SOMEWORD`

So I need to extract everything after the string `(type)/`

What is the GREL function for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the 'SOMEWORD' is always the last part of the string, you can also use:

```
value.split("/")[-1]
```

or

```
value.rpartition("/")[2]
```

If you have URLs which don't contain a 'type' where you don't want the same outcome, you can filter the rows to only those containing the type(s) before you do the GREL

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `match()` function and a regular expression :

```
value.match(/.+\/(.+)/)[0]
```

Or to be more precise:

```
value.match(/.+\(type\)\/(.+)/)[0]
```

Result :

[image]